# Why webrtc library not found in maven repo?

Tags: webrtc-android

According to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webrtc/google-webrtc/1.0.32006 , following code added in my gradle script.

```
implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006'
```

But gradle prompts me that the reop can not be found.

Comment: Did you add `https://dl.bintray.com/google/webrtc/` as a separate repository in your build.gradle file?